# How to set status bar icon color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, icons, flutter-dependencies

I'm working on the flutter project, I want to give the white colour to the status-bar icon. so I used the following line of code, and it gave me the result on a splash screen

FLUTTER CODE:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
  systemNavigationBarColor:  Color(0xffdedede),
  systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  systemNavigationBarDividerColor: null,
  statusBarColor: Color(0xffbf0000),
  statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
  statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
  ));
```

BUT: when the app navigates to the home screen, the status-bar icon colour change back to black, I don't know what is missing from that line's code. So I'm stuck on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colour of status-bar icon is depend on color of appbar. You can try edit `systemOverlayStyle` of AppBar on Home Screen ?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/systemOverlayStyle.html

Comment: Thank you, men; this works like a champion. I just added these lines of code on the app bar of the home screen. systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle(
              statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
              status bar brightness: Brightness.dark,// Status bar
            )

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to put it for the whole app, you can put it in your top level main() function like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light
  ));
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

It's possible to make it change during the runtime.

This code has been tested with **iOS 15.2**, **Flutter 3.10.6**